# unstable manifold in 2d dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have 2d dynamical non-linear system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with exactly two stable attractors $x_{1} = ( a\quad  b)^{T}$ and  $x_{2} = (c\quad d)^{T}$ and one saddle point (One eigenvalue of the linearized system is always positive, and the other one can be positive or negative.) Moreover, I can show that the system never goes to infinity and has no limit cycle, so that it basically reaches one of the attractor.

Is there a way to compute the unstable manifold (or another trick), to know whether the point $(a\quad d)^{T}$ will end-up in $x_{1}$ or in $x_{2}$ ? I can of course do the simulations, but my aim is to find conditions on $f$ such that this is the case.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you asking a general question about dynamical systems, or do you have a specific dynamical system in mind?

Comment: @John: It's a general question.

Comment: @John: I only know $f$ is smooth and has three zeros.

Comment: Do you actually want to calculate the separatrix for the two basins of attraction? You can solve your problem if you have some potential $\varphi$ for $f$, i.e., $f = \nabla\varphi$.

Comment: Calculating the separatrix would be great, but for me it is sufficient to know on which side of the separatrix is the point $(a\ d)^{T}$. Using a potential would require that $\frac{\partial f_{x}}{dy}=\frac{\partial f_{y}}{dx}$, right?

Comment: Yes, the field must be circulation free for that purpose. The location of the separatrix is at the location of the ridge of the potential. The ridge can be calculated as enveloppe of a family of curves $x\mapsto \varphi(x,y)$ with $y$ as parameter (or the other way around $y\mapsto \varphi(x,y)$ with $x$ as parameter).